# Apache24 and Mysql 2017

Tags: mysql, apache

I've just completed a fresh install of windows with no problems.
But I'm having trouble with my Apache 24 server and Mysql 5 server.
Both servers work but will not start automatically.
I have uninstalled both servers and reinstalled but the problems remain.
What I have tried:

```
System file checker. No issues
Services.msc is set to start both Apache24 and Mysql automatically.
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth and
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth: No corruption.
net stop wuauserv
net stop cryptSvc
net stop bits
net stop msiserver
ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 catroot2.old
net start wuauserv
net start cryptSvc
net start bits
net start msiserver
netstat -ano shows only Apache24 running on 80 and
nothing is using 80 when the server is stopped.

Troubleshooting Pack Cabinet
wu17059.diagcab
```

I truly believe it is windows issue because when I run the above troubleshooter 
Apache will start automatically on restart. If I shut down my computer and restart Apache and Mysql do not start automatically.

Comment: It is a long time since i used Windows but in the old Window versions you had to put the software in the startup folder to start it automatically when it is booting.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have Apache monitor in startup. I also tried putting HTTPD in there oops. It looks for all the dlls so I removed it.

Comment: The answer to my question was to put in a new wifi card. Problem solved.